# How to compare data from two tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

- **table's name:** registrationdate

[image]

I want to get the maximum value on last_update's column, so I use this query:

```
SELECT idtemp, max(last_update) FROM `registrationdate`
```

then the result will be like this:

[image]

and I have table like this:

- **table's name:** temp

[image]

then I want to compare *max(last_update)* in `registrationdate's table` and `generatedtime` in `temp's table`

this is the schema:

[image]

what may I do so that I can get table like that? Thanks in advance.

Fyi, *idtemp* in `registrationdate's table` = *id* in `temp's table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT ID AS ID,
       generatedTime AS generatedTime,
       tempTable AS tempTable,
       CASE
           WHEN generatedTime < maxLastUpdate THEN
               'not'
           ELSE
               'update'
       END AS UPDATEorNot
FROM temp
JOIN ( SELECT idtemp AS idtemp,
              MAX( last_update ) AS maxLastUpdate
       FROM registrationdate
       GROUP BY idtemp
     ) AS maxLastUpdateFinder ON temp.ID = maxLastUpdateFinder.idtemp;
```

**Assumptions**

That records in `temp` that do not have at least one matching record in `registrationdate` do not need to be included in the output.

That the comparison and sample data are valid and the sample output's `UPDATEorNot` field should read `not`.

**Explanation**

This statement starts with a subquery that finds each unique value of `idtemp` in `registrationdate` and the most recent value of `last_update` associated with it.

An `INNER JOIN` is then performed between `temp` and the results of the subquery so that each record in `temp` with at least one corresponding record in `registrationdate` is retained and has its corresponding most recent value of `last_update` appended to it.

The fields from `temp` are then `SELECT`ed, and a `CASE` statement used to determine the value to be selected for each record's `UPDATEorNot` field.

Please note that my statement will return `not` when the comparison that you supplied is applied to the sample data.  If you want `update` to be chosen then you will need to change your comparison from `generatedTime < max( last_update )` to `generatedTime > max( last_update )`, or to correct your sample data.

**Testing**

My statement was tested against a sample database created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE registrationdate
(
    last_update   DATETIME,
    idtemp        INT
);
INSERT INTO registrationdate ( last_update,
                               idtemp )
VALUES ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 ),
       ( '2017-05-12 14:20:58', 0 );
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    ID              INT,
    generatedTime   DATETIME,
    tempTable       VARCHAR( 50 )
);
INSERT INTO temp ( ID,
                   generatedTime,
                   tempTable )
VALUES ( 0, '2017-05-01 14:37:00', 'temp_pelamardoktorjk'                ),
       ( 2, '2017-05-01 14:37:00', 'temp_pelamarmagisteripk'             ),
       ( 3, '2017-05-01 14:38:00', 'temp_pelamarmagisterstatusinstitusi' ),
       ( 4, '2017-05-01 14:38:00', 'temp_pelamarmagisterusia'            ),
       ( 5, '2017-05-01 14:38:00', 'temp_pelamarmagisterstatusinstansi'  );
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

**Appendix 1**

The following is an alternative form of the above statement...

```
SELECT ID AS ID,
       generatedTime AS generatedTime,
       tempTable AS tempTable,
       CASE
           WHEN generatedTime < MAX( last_update ) THEN
               'not'
           ELSE
               'update'
       END AS UPDATEorNot
FROM temp
JOIN registrationdate ON temp.ID = registrationdate.idtemp
GROUP BY ID,
         generatedTime,
         tempTable;
```

**Appendix 2**

Please try the following attempted rewrite of the linked to code...

```
SELECT 
       generatedTime AS generatedTime,
       tempTable AS tempTable,
       CASE
           WHEN ( ( generatedTime < ( SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxPelamarmhsdoktor
                                      FROM pelamarmhsdoktor ) ) OR
                  ( generatedTime < ( SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxAkdmstmayor
                                      FROM akdmst_mayor ) ) OR
                  ( generatedTime < ( SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxIpbmstdepartemen
                                      FROM ipbmst_departemen ) ) OR
                  ( generatedTime < ( SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxIpbmstfakultas
                                      FROM ipbmst_fakultas ) ) OR
                  ( generatedTime < ( SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxIpbrefjeniskelamin
                                      FROM ipbref_jeniskelamin ) ) OR
                  ( generatedTime < ( SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxJenisinstansi
                                      FROM jenisinstansi ) ) OR
                  ( generatedTime < ( SELECT MAX( last_update ) AS maxJenisinstitusi
                                      FROM jenisinstitusi
                                    ) ) ) THEN
               'Yes'
           ELSE
               'No'
       END AS NeedsToUpdateOrNot
FROM generatedTime;
```

Comment: Wow you're totally awesome. Your answer totally help me. Thank you so much toonice. May you have a nice day. GBU ;)

Comment: I tried to make view table from that query, but the result is error because view table doesn't allow subquery. Is there any alternative way so that I can make view table from query that you gave?

Comment: I have posted an alternative form that does not use a subquery.  I chose the form from the top of my Answer because I believe it is slightly more efficient.  Please get back to me if the alternative is found wanting in some way.

Comment: how about joining more than one table?

Comment: how to change the structure so that I can make the view of this pastebin.com/jgJd62wm ?

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying - I have been busy with other Questions.  I am not too experienced with Views, but I have posted some code that you can try whilst I am researching this matter some more.

Comment: Thankyou so much toonice for helping me ;)